# How can I get normalized coordinated from an object in images

Tags: c#, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, object-recognition, microsoft-custom-vision

I am building a custom vision application with Microsoft's CustomVision.ai.

I am using this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/csharp-tutorial-od

At one point I need to:

> When you tag images in object detection projects, you need to specify the region of each tagged object using normalized coordinates

And to do that I need to write the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, double[]> fileToRegionMap = new Dictionary<string, double[]>() {
// FileName, Left, Top, Width, Height
{"scissors_1", new double[] { 0.4007353, 0.194068655, 0.259803921, 0.6617647 } },
{"scissors_2", new double[] { 0.426470578, 0.185898721, 0.172794119, 0.5539216 } },
{"scissors_3", new double[] { 0.289215684, 0.259428144, 0.403186262, 0.421568632 } }
...
```

where the double is the object's normalized coordinates inside the image.

How can I get those coordinates from images? Is there a software I can use to create those coordinates and the add them to the code?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: [Object detection with Microsoft Custom Vision](https://www.henkboelman.com/object-detection-with-microsoft-custom-vision/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalized coordinates are coordinates that range from 0.0 to 1.0 (exclusive).

If you have an image with coordinates in the range

```
(X = 0..Width, Y = 0..Height)
```

transform the coordinates with

```
double x_normalized = X / Width;
double y_normalized = Y / Height;
```

This assumes that either the coordinate `X` or `Y` or the `Width` or `Height` is given as `double` or `float`. If they are given as `int`, use

```
double x_normalized = (double)X / Width;
double y_normalized = (double)Y / Height;
```

the same applies for a width or height of an object inside the image

```
double object_width_normalized = object_width / Width;
double object_height_normalized = object_height / Height;
```

Note, if the coordinates are given as `int`, usually they are in the range `[0..Width - 1, 0..Height - 1`, so that the division yields a value `0.0 <= value < 1.0`.

Comment: I will try to build a console application and do the transformation as a test. Thank you!